# maven - Can't release project due to non released dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am using a multi-module pom setup and when using the release plugin I am unable to do so.
I get the error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project libraryparent: Can't release project due to non released dependencies :
com.xyz:libraryparent:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT
in project 'utils' (com.xyz:utils:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT)
```

the command I runs is:

```
mvn -B release:clean release:prepare release:perform -DdryRun=true -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.1
```

Here is the major portions of the files that I think is relevant:

### libraryparent

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
  <artifactId>libraryparent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>parent library</name>
  <description>A parent pom for all library modules</description>

    <modules>
        <module>../util</module>
        <module>../streams</module>
    </modules>

  <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
            <goals>deploy assembly:single</goals>
            <!--
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            -->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

### util

```
<project .....>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>util</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId> 
        <artifactId>libraryparent</artifactId> 
        <relativePath>../libraryparent/pom.xml</relativePath>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    </parent>
</project>
```

### streams

```
<project .....>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>streams</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraryparent</artifactId> 
        <relativePath>../libraryparent/pom.xml</relativePath>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <!--
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            -->
            <classifier>j2me</classifier>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I would suspect that the release plugin can set the versions to their release versions,etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Hm, possibly you need to add the modules to the dependency management in your parent pom

Comment: I think you need to run release plugin on the parent, not on module.

Comment: Arkadiy, I did run the command on the parent pom. I guessed that
I need not paste all the "garbage" as it would clutter the question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `maven-release-plugin` verifies if the parent and dependencies are part of the multimodule project. If it's not recognized it's either because of a different version or because of a typo in the groupId and/or artifactId. `com.xyz` is probably fake, so please check that value again. 
Some may say that flat-projects (like this one) are not supported by the maven-release-plugin. However, there are a lot of integration-tests which do confirm that flat projects are supported.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the answer. Yes the artifactID is fake and
and only posted it as such. The actual project is quite large, with 26 or so libraries that are interdependant; the parent is just there 
for an easy build process. The parent makes also for easy administering the project as it defines some common properties.

Comment: I have just checked and made 100% sure that all, artifactId ,
groupId and version match 100% accross the poms. No typo there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just found the solution,

I will do a more complete test and post results shortly.

Change the maven-release-plugin goals from this:

```
          <goals>deploy assembly:single</goals>
```

to this

```
          <goals>deploy</goals>
```

...the end...

Comment: I solved my initial problem but there is more; 

And that is the way the project is structured or unknown yet. Each library has its own git repo and the parent too. Close to the end of the build procedure, I am getting this error message:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5:prepare (default-cli) on project libraryparent: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-add command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: '....\libraries\util\pom.xml' is outside repository

Comment: That doesn't explain the `Can't release project due to non released dependencies`-message though. And yes: the maven-release-plugin assumes 1 release cycle per git repository and no mixtures of repositories.